# How can I extract a substring from a character column without using SUBSTR()?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a questions regarding below data.

You clearly can see each `EMP_IDENTIFIER`  has connected with  `EMP_ID`.
So I need to pull only identifier which is 10 characters that will insert another column.
How would I do that?

I did some traditional way, using `INSTR`, `SUBSTR`. 
I just want to know is there any other way to do it but  not using `INSTR`, `SUBSTR`.

```
EMP_ID(VARCHAR2)EMP_IDENTIFIER(VARCHAR2)
62049       62049-2162400111
6394        6394-1368000222
64473       64473-1814702333
61598       61598-0876000444
57452       57452-0336503555
5842        5842-0000070666
75778       75778-0955501777
76021       76021-0546004888
76274       76274-0000454999
73910       73910-0574500122
```

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would explain WHY you don't want to use `instr()` and `substr()`, which are hands-down the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Mathguy-there is no reason for it, just want to know is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Oh - you mean for learning? That is OK, as long as you understand for the problem you posted (but perhaps not in other situations) instr/substr is indeed the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second part of the identifier and it is always 10 characters:

```
select t.*, substr(emp_identifier, -10) as secondpart
from t;
```

Comment: so SUBSTR must use, right?  is there any other way, we can use REG_EXP , I  am not sure. yeah that method I am using too.

Comment: @Sohel - WHY do you want to use `regexp_substr()`? When `substr()` is much faster, more natural, easier to maintain, ... ?

Comment: @Sohel . . . There is no reason to use `regexp_substr()`.  This is simpler to read and should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
   REGEXP_SUBSTR (EMP_IDENTIFIER, '-(.{10})',1,1,null,1)
```

That will give the 1st 10 character string that follows a dash ("-") in your string.  Thanks to mathguy for the improvement.

Beyond that, you'll have to provide more details on the exact logic for picking out the identifier you want.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Look like something I can learn here. can you please explain string definition like what this guys is doing here  , '\-.*$'), '-'

Comment: Without `LTRIM`:  `REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMP_IDENTIFIER, '-(.*)', 1, 1, null, 1)`

Comment: Or `REGEXP_SUBSTR (EMP_IDENTIFIER, '-(.{10})',1,1,null,1)`, since he knows it to be 10 characters.  Thanks for the syntax, @mathguy

Comment: Note that `-` doesn't need to be escaped, it has no special meaning except in a matching character set.

Comment: @sohel The string, now '-(.{10})' in the answer` is a regular expression than describes a pattern to look for.  Basically, a dash, then any 10 characters.  The period (".") means "any character" and the "{10}" means 10 of them.  The parentheses put the 10 characters into a "subexpression" that excludes the dash, so that they can be returned as the answer.  The last parameter, the "1", tells `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to use the 1st subexpression as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently this is for learning purposes... let's say the assignment was more complicated. Let's say you had a longer input string, and it had several groups separated by -, and the groups could include letters and digits. You know there are at least two groups that are "digits only" and you need to grab the second such "purely numeric" group. Then something like this will work (and there will not be an instr/substr solution):

```
select regexp_substr(input_str, '(-|^)(\d+)(-|$)', 1, 2, null, 2) from ....
```

This searches the input string for one or more digits ( `\d` means any digit, `+` means one or more occurrences) between a `-` or the beginning of the string (`^` means beginning of the string; `(a|b)` means match `a` OR `b`) and a `-` or the end of the string (`$` means end of the string). It starts searching at the first character (the second argument of the function is 1); it looks for the second occurrence (the argument 2); it doesn't do any special matching such as ignore case (the argument "null" to the function), and when the match is found, return the fragment of the match pattern included in the second set of parentheses (the last argument, 2, to the regexp function). The second fragment is the `\d+` - the sequence of digits, without the leading and/or trailing dash `-`.

This solution will work in your example too, it's just overkill. It will find the right "digits-only" group in something like AS23302-ATX-20032-33900293-CWV20-3499-RA; it will return the second numeric group, 33900293.